# PHP: mysqli_query and die()

Tags: php

**The code:**

I am testing the simple code below to insert data into my database:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (Age) VALUES (35) WHERE FirstName='John'") or die("Error");
```

In my db I do not have a row where `FirstName=John` (it is part of the test).

**What I am expecting to see:**

Because there is no row in my db where `FirstName=John`, I am expecting `die()` to send to me the error message.

**The problem:**

`Die()` does not send to me the error message. In fact I have observed that `die()` only sends to me the error message when it can not connect to db.

**What I think:**

Well, may be it is how `die()` works... But then how to get informed when a query is not executed for reasons other than no connection?

Answer (score 2):

This is normal. mysqli_query will only return FALSE if the query *fails*, that is an SQL-level occurs. A 0-affected rows query is not considered a failure (just like an empty result from a SELECT query is not a failure). In those cases mysqli_query will return TRUE.

What you want to do is check the value of `$con->affected_rows` to get the number of rows affected by the last query, and if that equals 0, die.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is a valid query and therefore the mysqli_query returns true, thus die will not get called

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the manual, `"mysqli_query()` returns `FALSE` on failure. For successful `SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE` or `EXPLAIN` queries `mysqli_query()` will return a `mysqli_result object`. For other successful queries `mysqli_query(`) will return `TRUE."`

So there is no failure if you have no row where `FirstName=John`

You can use [`mysqli_affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) to return the number of rows inserted

Answer (score 0):

`Die()` didn't fire because the query successfully ran. It just didn't update anything because there was no row with a first name of `John`.

You should check with `affected_rows` to see if any rows were modified with the query.

Answer (score 0):

there is no error on your sql, it's just that you don't have a row, you can do an if with the amount of results if that's what you want to figure out
in here you have a procedural and an object oriented solution.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

in your case to know if there was an error:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

or to know the results

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Name FROM City LIMIT 10")) {
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", mysqli_num_rows($result));

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```